# How to join two Boost Hana maps?

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming, boost-hana

I have two `boost::hana::map`s to join together.

```cpp
constexpr auto m1 = hana::make_map( 
    hana::make_pair("key1"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>), 
    hana::make_pair("key2"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>) 
); 

constexpr auto m2 = hana::make_map( 
    hana::make_pair("key3"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>), 
    hana::make_pair("key4"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>), 
    hana::make_pair("key5"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>) 
);
```

How to get map containing both of it, as below?

```cpp
constexpr auto result = hana::make_map( 
    hana::make_pair("key1"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>), 
    hana::make_pair("key2"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>), 
    hana::make_pair("key3"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>), 
    hana::make_pair("key4"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>), 
    hana::make_pair("key5"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>) 
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Newer version

<sup>*(Boost.Hana > 1.2, Boost >= 1.65)*</sup>

There is `boost::hana::union_` function for joining `boost::hana::map`s.

> Returns the union of two maps.
>
> Given two maps `xs` and `ys`, `hana::union_(xs, ys)` is a new map containing all the elements of `xs` and all the elements of `ys`, without duplicates.
>   If both `xs` and `ys` contain an element with the same key, the one in `ys` is taken.

[Cite from Boost.Hana docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1map.html#acd511f2c01f38405bfba0b6d5b2922e8)

There is also example:

```cpp
// Simple example
constexpr auto m1 = hana::make_map(
    hana::make_pair("key1"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>),
    hana::make_pair("key2"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>)
);
constexpr auto m2 = hana::make_map(
    hana::make_pair("key3"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>),
    hana::make_pair("key4"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>),
    hana::make_pair("key5"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>)
);
BOOST_HANA_CONSTANT_CHECK(hana::union_(m1, m2) == hana::make_map(
       hana::make_pair("key1"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>),
       hana::make_pair("key2"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>),
       hana::make_pair("key3"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>),
       hana::make_pair("key4"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>),
       hana::make_pair("key5"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>)
));

// Example with overwriting pair (the same key)
constexpr auto m3 = hana::make_map(
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<int>, hana::int_c<1>),
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<bool>, hana::bool_c<true>)
);
constexpr auto m4 = hana::make_map(
       hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<char>, hana::char_c<'c'>),
       hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<bool>, hana::bool_c<false>)
);
BOOST_HANA_CONSTANT_CHECK(hana::union_(m3, m4) == hana::make_map(
       hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<int>, hana::int_c<1>),
       hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<bool>, hana::bool_c<false>),
       hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<char>, hana::char_c<'c'>)
));
```

Full working interactive example [here on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/FFAdnW) online compiler.

---

### Older versions

<sup>*(Boost.Hana <= 1.1, Boost <= 1.64)*</sup>

Based on modified example from [some Boost forums topic](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Boost-Hana-how-to-merge-two-or-more-maps-td4687834.html).

```cpp
constexpr auto map1 = hana::make_map( 
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<TwoOtherKeys1>,      hana::type_c<SomeValue>),
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<SameKey_SameType>,   hana::type_c<SomeValue>),
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<SameKey_DifferType>, hana::type_c<SomeValue>)
);
constexpr auto map2 = hana::make_map( 
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<TwoOtherKeys2>,      hana::type_c<SomeValue>), 
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<SameKey_SameType>,   hana::type_c<SomeValue>), 
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<SameKey_DifferType>, hana::type_c<OtherValue>) 
); 

// Creates result sequence by inserting all of (source) `map1` sequence into (initial) `map1` sequence. 
// Since both sequences are maps with unique keys, keys that exist in both source and initial map got overwrited.
constexpr auto result = hana::fold(map1, map2, hana::insert);

// Excepted result
constexpr auto expected = hana::make_map(
    // Diffrent keys pairs are copied.
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<TwoOtherKeys1>, hana::type_c<SomeValue>),
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<TwoOtherKeys2>, hana::type_c<SomeValue>),

    // The same key and type pairs are just passed.
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<SameKey_SameType>, hana::type_c<SomeValue>),   

    // The same key, differ type - overwrited.
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<SameKey_DifferType>, hana::type_c<OtherValue>)
);

// Assertion to confirm exceptation
static_assert(result == expected, ""); // OK
```

Full working interactive example [here on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/G1TyYX) online compiler.

The solution works exacly the same as the one in newest version of Boost.Hana.

---

All credits for the soulution to [Louis Dionne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/627587/louis-dionne).